# How can I take pseudo:after { content: "Value"; } value dynamically in this snippet?

Tags: html, css

I have a little css snippet here: http://jsfiddle.net/cr6Hm/ (Similar example can be found on http://9gag.com/)

Basically, it shows a small div on the `Notifications` link with `New` text written on it.

Right now, `New` text is writtenon the div using `pseudo:after` and it works.

```
// This one works
.text-new:after {
    content: 'New';
}
```

However, I want to change `New` text dynamically. (e.g I want to display amount of notifications instead of new)

I don't know how can I do it since I don't exactly know how `pseudo:after` works.

Basically, it should be something like this:

```
<span class="popup popup-greenish">
    <i class="text>{{ $amount_notifications }}</i>
    Notifications
</span>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you want to use javascript to do this?

Comment: Pure CSS if possible.

Comment: JSfiddle doesn't work

Comment: It does. Look at the "New" text on the top right side.

Comment: OK...it's just not positioned correctly. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires an attribute such as this:

```
<span class="test" data-count="123">...</span>
```

And CSS:

```css
.test:after {
    content: attr(data-count);
}
```

Note that the attribute MUST be on the element that the psuedo-element belongs to.

Comment: I didn't see this usage before, so I believe it's not compatiple with old browsers? If it's not supported on IE9, I can rewrite whole CSS logic from stratch.

Comment: Thank you. I'll pick this as the correct answer in few minutes - one thing, though. Does it have to be prefixed with `data`?

Comment: No, it does not, however using `data-*` is the standards-compliant way of using custom attributes.